# Struggling to create python3 debian packages

Tags: python3, deb, packaging

I setup https://github.com/MirahezeBots/MirahezeBots/pull/436 which should run make-deb then dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc but that doesn't seem to work per https://github.com/MirahezeBots/MirahezeBots/pull/436/checks?check_run_id=1919896022

When I run it locally, the changelog doesn't seem to be well generated but I also see mentions of python2.

Is make-deb still functional or is there a way to create a debian changelog based off my changelog file / a good way to format it?

How do I also ensure the package will prefer python3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give this a read it may help. https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html

Comment: I got as far as https://github.com/MirahezeBots/MirahezeBots/pull/436/checks?check_run_id=1928759111 @HappyTux but not sure what to do about the opt issue.

Comment: As in it uses /opt for the install directory, that should be set with an option  --install-dir= or some such idea` passed into the make file or directly changing the make files install target.

Comment: Where/how would that be set? All the current config is https://github.com/MirahezeBots/MirahezeBots/tree/RhinosF1-patch-5/debian

Comment: I have no clue you do not show the make file this is where your INSTALL: target is contained, the ,/configure step is where you pass in the --install-dir= or --prefix= depends how it is done by reading in the file or using --help to get it shown to you. In the top level directory of the source it is usually there, the Make  or an autogen file to generate one.

Comment: The errros are coming from a CI tool. There's no other configuration than what is in the Debian folder. I assume that --install-dir should be added to a command ran by dpkg-buildpackage which would mean changing something in the rules file but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I was trying to turn off dh-virtualenv to use system python with https://github.com/MirahezeBots/MirahezeBots/pull/438/checks?check_run_id=1934242457 but that just refuses to install anything.

Comment: There has to be more than that to the packaging you show on the github, there is no source to build. That is where your make file is.

Comment: You can see exactly what the workflow runs and the full source in that repo. No magic. It's all in the Debian workflow.